# Shader uniforms not showing up

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I can not get this shader to return its uniforms.

I have looked everywhere for a possible problem with my shader assembler or bindings. I even rebooted my machine (desktop quad core) thinking maybe the OpenGL driver crapped out.

Here's the code that tries but fails to get the uniform locations:

```
Private Sub set_deferredLighting_variables()
    deferred_cam_position = Gl.glGetUniformLocation(shader_list.deferred_shader, "viewPos")
    deferred_light_position = Gl.glGetUniformLocation(shader_list.deferred_shader, "Light_position")
    deferred_gcolor = Gl.glGetUniformLocation(shader_list.deferred_shader, "gColor")
    deferred_gnormal = Gl.glGetUniformLocation(shader_list.deferred_shader, "gNormal")
    deferred_gposition = Gl.glGetUniformLocation(shader_list.deferred_shader, "gPosition")
End Sub
```

And here is the fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 FragColor;
uniform sampler2D gPosition;
uniform sampler2D gNormal;
uniform sampler2D gColor;
uniform vec3 Light_position;
uniform vec3 viewPos;

void main()
{             
    vec3 light_Color = vec3 (1.0, 1.0, 0.9);
    // Retrieve data from G-buffer
    vec3 FragPos = texture(gPosition, TexCoords).rgb;
    vec3 Normal = texture(gNormal, TexCoords).rgb;
    vec3 Albedo = texture(gColor, TexCoords).rgb;
    float Specular = texture(gNormal, TexCoords).a;

    // Then calculate lighting as usual
    vec3 lighting = Albedo * 0.1; // hard-coded ambient component
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);

    // Diffuse
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(Light_position - FragPos);
    vec3 diffuse = max(dot(Normal, lightDir), 0.0) * Albedo * light_Color;

    FragColor = vec4(lighting + diffuse, 1.0);
}
```

For the life of me I can't find a reason why the uniforms are not showing up.
I have a very very good shader assembler that checks at every stage for the status and any glGetError. If glGetError returns anything but 0, it throws up a message box. My assembler reads and builds the shaders in the folder.. Naming of the shaders is critical. The assembler builds 20+ shaders with no problem including this one.. There are absolutely no errors thrown!

I had this issue once a few months back and rebooting fixed the problem.. I tried that.. No luck.
Any help would be fantastic!

Here is the shader assembler code: Not how crazy I am at checking every thing.

```
    Public Function assemble_shader(v As String, g As String, f As String, ByRef shader As Integer, ByRef name As String, ByRef has_geo As Boolean) As Integer
    Dim vs(1) As String
    Dim gs(1) As String
    Dim fs(1) As String
    Dim vertexObject As Integer
    Dim geoObject As Integer
    Dim fragmentObject As Integer
    Dim status_code As Integer
    Dim info As New StringBuilder
    info.Length = 1024
    Dim info_l As Integer


    If shader > 0 Then
        Gl.glUseProgram(0)
        Gl.glDeleteProgram(shader)
        Gl.glGetProgramiv(shader, Gl.GL_DELETE_STATUS, status_code)
        Gl.glFinish()
    End If

    Dim e = Gl.glGetError
    If e <> 0 Then
        Dim s = Glu.gluErrorString(e)
        Dim ms As String = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
        'MsgBox("Function: " + ms + vbCrLf + "Error! " + s, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "OpenGL Issue")
    End If
    'have a hard time with files remaining open.. hope this fixes it! (yep.. it did)
    Using vs_s As New StreamReader(v)
        vs(0) = vs_s.ReadToEnd
        vs_s.Close()
        vs_s.Dispose()
    End Using
    Using fs_s As New StreamReader(f)
        fs(0) = fs_s.ReadToEnd
        fs_s.Close()
        fs_s.Dispose()
    End Using
    If has_geo Then
        Using gs_s As New StreamReader(g)
            gs(0) = gs_s.ReadToEnd
            gs_s.Close()
            gs_s.Dispose()
        End Using
    End If


    vertexObject = Gl.glCreateShader(Gl.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    fragmentObject = Gl.glCreateShader(Gl.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    shader = Gl.glCreateProgram()

    ' Compile vertex shader
    Gl.glShaderSource(vertexObject, 1, vs, vs(0).Length)
    Gl.glCompileShader(vertexObject)
    Gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexObject, 8192, info_l, info)
    Gl.glGetShaderiv(vertexObject, Gl.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, status_code)
    If Not status_code = Gl.GL_TRUE Then
        Gl.glDeleteShader(vertexObject)
        gl_error(name + "_vertex didn't compile!" + vbCrLf + info.ToString)
        'Return
    End If

    e = Gl.glGetError
    If e <> 0 Then
        Dim s = Glu.gluErrorString(e)
        Dim ms As String = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
        MsgBox("Function: " + ms + vbCrLf + "Error! " + s, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "OpenGL Issue")
    End If

    If has_geo Then
        'geo
        geoObject = Gl.glCreateShader(Gl.GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER_EXT)
        Gl.glShaderSource(geoObject, 1, gs, gs(0).Length)
        Gl.glCompileShader(geoObject)
        Gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(geoObject, 8192, info_l, info)
        Gl.glGetShaderiv(geoObject, Gl.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, status_code)
        If Not status_code = Gl.GL_TRUE Then
            Gl.glDeleteShader(geoObject)
            gl_error(name + "_geo didn't compile!" + vbCrLf + info.ToString)
            'Return
        End If
        e = Gl.glGetError
        If e <> 0 Then
            Dim s = Glu.gluErrorString(e)
            Dim ms As String = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
            MsgBox("Function: " + ms + vbCrLf + "Error! " + s, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "OpenGL Issue")
        End If
        Gl.glProgramParameteriEXT(shader, Gl.GL_GEOMETRY_INPUT_TYPE_EXT, Gl.GL_TRIANGLES)
        Gl.glProgramParameteriEXT(shader, Gl.GL_GEOMETRY_OUTPUT_TYPE_EXT, Gl.GL_LINE_STRIP)
        If name.Contains("normal") Then
            Gl.glProgramParameteriEXT(shader, Gl.GL_GEOMETRY_VERTICES_OUT_EXT, 18)
        Else
            Gl.glProgramParameteriEXT(shader, Gl.GL_GEOMETRY_VERTICES_OUT_EXT, 4) 'leaf needs 4
        End If
        e = Gl.glGetError
        If e <> 0 Then
            Dim s = Glu.gluErrorString(e)
            Dim ms As String = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
            MsgBox("Function: " + ms + vbCrLf + "Error! " + s, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "OpenGL Issue")
        End If

    End If

    ' Compile fragment shader

    Gl.glShaderSource(fragmentObject, 1, fs, fs(0).Length)
    Gl.glCompileShader(fragmentObject)
    Gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentObject, 8192, info_l, info)
    Gl.glGetShaderiv(fragmentObject, Gl.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, status_code)

    If Not status_code = Gl.GL_TRUE Then
        Gl.glDeleteShader(fragmentObject)
        gl_error(name + "_fragment didn't compile!" + vbCrLf + info.ToString)
        'Return
    End If
    e = Gl.glGetError
    If e <> 0 Then
        Dim s = Glu.gluErrorString(e)
        Dim ms As String = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
        MsgBox("Function: " + ms + vbCrLf + "Error! " + s, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "OpenGL Issue")
    End If

    'attach shader objects
    Gl.glAttachShader(shader, fragmentObject)
    If has_geo Then
        Gl.glAttachShader(shader, geoObject)
    End If
    Gl.glAttachShader(shader, vertexObject)

    'link program
    Gl.glLinkProgram(shader)

    ' detach shader objects
    Gl.glDetachShader(shader, fragmentObject)
    If has_geo Then
        Gl.glDetachShader(shader, geoObject)
    End If
    Gl.glDetachShader(shader, vertexObject)

    e = Gl.glGetError
    If e <> 0 Then
        Dim s = Glu.gluErrorString(e)
        Dim ms As String = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
        MsgBox("Function: " + ms + vbCrLf + "Error! " + s, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "OpenGL Issue")
    End If

    Gl.glGetShaderiv(shader, Gl.GL_LINK_STATUS, status_code)

    If Not status_code = Gl.GL_TRUE Then
        Gl.glDeleteProgram(shader)
        gl_error(name + " did not link!" + vbCrLf + info.ToString)
        'Return
    End If

    'delete shader objects
    Gl.glDeleteShader(fragmentObject)
    Gl.glGetShaderiv(fragmentObject, Gl.GL_DELETE_STATUS, status_code)
    If has_geo Then
        Gl.glDeleteShader(geoObject)
        Gl.glGetShaderiv(geoObject, Gl.GL_DELETE_STATUS, status_code)
    End If
    Gl.glDeleteShader(vertexObject)
    Gl.glGetShaderiv(vertexObject, Gl.GL_DELETE_STATUS, status_code)
    e = Gl.glGetError
    If e <> 0 Then
        'aways throws a error after deletion even though the status shows them as deleted.. ????
        Dim s = Glu.gluErrorString(e)
        Dim ms As String = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
        'MsgBox("Function: " + ms + vbCrLf + "Error! " + s, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "OpenGL Issue")
    End If
    vs(0) = Nothing
    fs(0) = Nothing
    If has_geo Then
        gs(0) = Nothing
    End If
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete()

    Return shader
End Function
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you include how you create, compile, attach and link the shaders and programs.

Comment: I can but its a boat load of code with all the status checks and glGetError checks I have in it. Like I said in the post.. I compiles 24 shaders with no issues providing the shaders have not issues in the syntax. I have found that nVidia is sloppy at what they will let go.. added a vec3 to a vec4 throws no error.. just a warning. I intentionally leave off a semicolon just to catch the warnings and fix them.
I'll post the part that assembles the shader for ya to look over.

Comment: I think there is something I'm missing.. I bind a MRT FBO.. render my geo.. do a glFinish.. switch back to the default FBO, put the context in ORTHO.. glUseProgram( that one),, bind my textures and its exactly like there is NO shader at all. If I glEnable(gl_Texture_2D), than it renders the first texture even though the shader is active. Its like the shader doesn't exist but it has a valid id issued from the shader assembler. I added code and printed out all the names and IDs of all the shaders the assembler builds and they are all good.. 3 to 24 (I think windows 7 uses the first 2). Me lost!

Comment: I found the problem... Incomplete Vertex Shader.. You would think that the compiler would throw some kind a warning when you are not outputting the vertex position. Wow.. I need to take a break from this.